# htaccess to redirect NON-html links (ex: https://my-site.com/stuff) to the corresponding .html or .xml file (ex: user served content in stuff.html)

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

For example, for my website (let's call it **my-site.com**) I have an html file named **fudge.html**

Currently, if you were to type **my-site.com/fudge.html** (aka include the html extension in the URL), you would get directed to the correct page (aka served the contents of my **fudge.html** file). However, if you were to type in **my-site.com/fudge**, you would get a 404 error page.

**My Question:** How do I make it possible for my user to be able to type in **my-site.com/fudge** (does NOT include .html) AND ALSO **my-site.com/fudge.html** and get served the contents of my **fudge.html** file? Also, that if they visit **my-site.com**, they will get redirected to my-site.com/index.html

AKA how do I make sure that BOTH version of the urls (with .html AND without .html) will work?

(Why i want both non-html and html urls to work is because of SEO/ad revenue reasons - currently, all the urls of my website are indexed with the .html extension so I would have to resubmit all of URLS with the NON-html version and potentially wait weeks to months for it to be processed by Google search console (even if I submit my sitemap) and other tools.)

What I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On

// Redirect non-html to html file:

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]    // if filename is not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f.   // if filename.html exists
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [R=301]          // permanently redirect 



// Redirect requests to my-site.com (homepage) to my-site.com/index.html:

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} https://www.my-site.com [NC]
RewriteCond index.html -f
RewriteRule https://www.my-site.com https://www.my-site.com/index.html [R=301]  



// Redirect to sitemap.xml:

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} https://www.my-site.com/sitemap [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.xml -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.xml [R=301, L]
```

Am I on the right track? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: This one does not make any sense, remove it: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [NC]`

Comment: The trailing dot in that one has to be removed: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f.`

Comment: Why would you want to make an external redirection here: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [R=301]`? Why not use an internal rewrite and _keep_ the pretty short URL? Instead I would redirect the long URL with the "file name extension" to the short version.

Comment: About the `infex.html` thing: take a look at the `DirectoryIndex` directive `mod_dir` offers: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Comment: Remove `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} https://www.my-site.com/sitemap [NC]`, use a matching pattern in the rule instead: `RewriteRule ^/?sitemap$ /sitemap.xml [R=301, L]`. Or, more general: `RewriteRule ^/?(\w)$ $1.xml [R=301, L]`